# How can I fix this gap in the Ghostbusters Firehouse roof?

Tags: building

We built the LEGO [75827 Ghostbusters Firehouse](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=75827-1#T=S&O=%7B%7D) which was good fun.  But despite being pretty sure we have all of the pieces where they are supposed to go, there is a gap in the roof:

[image: firehouse with gap]

Yet it goes into place with a slight push:

[image]

So:

- What could be causing this?
- How can I fix it without glue?

Comment: I think it is not unusual for a structure to bend slightly. Especially when you stack long plates onto each other. Recently, I built a small car with three axes. It took some bending to make all wheels touch the ground.  Are there no studs to hold the roof in place?

Comment: Maybe it's because one of the outer edges isn't attached properly? This usually happens when attaching long/wide plates(as pointed out by Azira). Try pushing all the sides down all the way.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this but what I do is slightly warm the section on a radiator for a few minutes and then gently bend the pieces in situ, you might have to do it several times or even do it to individual pieces, I've noticed that lego sometimes has this problem. Or you could modify the corner of the building so that there is a piece that does come into contact with the roof- same colours etc (remember there was a technic model years ago that no one could get to work, lego did admit there was a design flaw and a mistake in the instruction booklet too).

Answer (score 1):

I have this set and it does the same thing for me. The problem is that the size of the model and the tolerances between bricks add up and by the time you have a structure of that size not everything fits perfectly.

First thing you should do is make sure all the pieces are properly seated all the way down the construction of the model. It is possible to make the pieces rest in the proper position.

If that still doesn't work for you, you can certainly fix it by replacing some of the tiles with plates. The building is meant to be modular, and thus easily disassembled into sections, for play/display purposes. If you rebuild it with plates instead of tiles it will have more structural strength but will be more difficult to disassemble.